# Why are some series temporarily missing from my Excel chart?

Tags: vba, excel, charts, macros

I am producing an Excel column chart from a VB macro. I added 3 horizontal reference lines and find that when the macro completes, only the first one appears (along with the column chart). However, if I save the workbook and reopen it, all 3 reference lines are visible. Alternatively, if I go to the design tab to "Select Data" and simply click on any one of the reference line names, all 3 immediately appear. Any ideas on what I can put in my macro to get them all to appear automatically when the macro completes?

The code that creates these 3 reference lines is (`sc` is the chart's `SeriesCollection`):

```
With sc.NewSeries
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    .Name = "A"
    .XValues = "={1,3}"
    .Values = "={100,100}"
End With
With sc.NewSeries
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    .Name = "B"
    .XValues = "={1, 3}"
    .Values = "={80, 80}"
End With
With sc.NewSeries
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    .Name = "C"
    .XValues = "={1, 3}"
    .Values = "={50, 50}"
End With
```

EDIT:  Here is a screenshot using the data in the answer by @axel-richter. This is what it looks like immediately after the macro ends.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you step through the code (F8) will it show up as expected?

Comment: Yes, shows up fine if I step through it.

Comment: `DoEvents` has no effect. On a hunch, I also tried `Application.Wait Now()` but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is with Excel 2010 and later.

Call [Chart.ChartWizard Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838804.aspx) without parameters after you added new series.

Example:

Suppose we have:

[image]

Then after running this macro:

```
Sub addChart()

 Dim oChart As ChartObject
 Dim sc As SeriesCollection

 Set oChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(300, 40, 300, 200)
 oChart.Chart.ChartWizard Source:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D4"), Gallery:=xlColumn

 Set sc = oChart.Chart.SeriesCollection

 With sc.NewSeries
  .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
  .Name = "A"
  .XValues = "={1,3}"
  .Values = "={100,100}"
 End With
 With sc.NewSeries
  .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
  .Name = "B"
  .XValues = "={1, 3}"
  .Values = "={80, 80}"
 End With
 With sc.NewSeries
  .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
  .Name = "C"
  .XValues = "={1, 3}"
  .Values = "={50, 50}"
 End With

 oChart.Chart.ChartWizard

End Sub
```

we have:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but when I run this very code I still get exactly the same problem - only the first line shows up.

Comment: What Excel version? Works for me with Excel 2016.

Comment: Office 365 - Excel 16.0.6965.2105

Comment: Are you sure you are calling `oChart.Chart.ChartWizard` after the adding the new series as it is done in my code? Please try exactly my example. If that works but your example don't work then  please describe exactly the difference between my example and yours.

Comment: Yes, I pasted your code and see only the line for A when the macro ends. (Although B and C are in the legend)

Answer (score 0):

I still have no explanation for why those lines don't show up for me, but I've found a "solution" that coerces them into visibility. I added the following at the end of the macro to (a) add an extra series at the end, and (b) immediately delete it.

```
With sc.NewSeries
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    .Name = "D"
    .XValues = "={1, 3}"
    .Values = "={50, 50}"
 End With
 sc(sc.Count).Select
 Application.SendKeys "{Delete}"
```

Note the last line. Using `Selection.Delete` deletes the extra series but the lines that were invisible stay that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the time try not reuse your SeriesCollection object.

I ran into this with a C# app I'm writing.  The only similarity I could see between our code was that we were both calling NewSeries() on the same SeriesCollection object.

It's also worth noting the Chartwizard, and quick-series-create-delete workaround methods didn't work for me.

What did work was calling seriescollection() on the chart object before each SeriesCollection.NewSeries() call.

As in:

```
ChartObject co = target.ChartObjects().Item(1);
Chart c = co.Chart;
SeriesCollection s = c.SeriesCollection();
Series s1 = s.NewSeries();
s1.ChartType = XlChartType.xlLine;

s = c.SeriesCollection();
Series s2 = s.NewSeries();
s2.ChartType = XlChartType.xlLine;
```

Total conjecture, but I suspect a defect in the SeriesCollection class; potentially some event isn't firing on subsequent NewSeries calls.  Depending on the version each of us is using the workarounds were causing the event that isn't firing to fire and therefore we would see the invisible series' actually appear.